# How do I set up a time loop in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemy;
    float defaultSpawnTime = 1f;
    float spawnTime = 1f;
    float realTime = 4f;
    
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        spawnTime-= Time.deltaTime;
        realTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (spawnTime < 0 && realTime<30f && realTime>5f)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.3f, 2.3f), 8f, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
            GameObject go1 = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.3f, 2.3f), 8f, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
      
            spawnTime = defaultSpawnTime;
            if (realTime > 30f)
            {
                realTime = 0f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My game is 2D.
In the game, a meteorite rains every 2 seconds from above.
The player struggles with these.

But since the game is very tiring, I do not want meteorites to rain for 5 seconds every 30 seconds, so the player will have the opportunity to rest.

I also wanted to create a time variable and increase it in real-time.
And I tried the meteor shower to happen, provided the time was between 5 and 30.

If the time is greater than 30, I wanted to return it to 0 and loop it, but after 30 it continues to progress.
I don't know where I went wrong, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the if statment outside of first if. Because after realtime > 30 you condition " && realTime<30f && " not fulfilled

```
void Update()
{
    spawnTime-= Time.deltaTime;
    realTime += Time.deltaTime;
    
    if (spawnTime < 0 && realTime<30f && realTime>5f)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.3f, 2.3f), 8f, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
        GameObject go1 = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.3f, 2.3f), 8f, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;

        spawnTime = defaultSpawnTime;
    }

    if (realTime > 30f)
    {
        realTime = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

It gets hard to manage time like that after you add few timers. Try using Coroutines like:

```
void Start(){
    StartMeteorShower(5f);
}

void StartMeteorShower(float time){
    StartCoroutine(StartMeteorShowerDelayed(time);
}

IEnumerator StartMeteorShowerDelayed(float delay){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    StartCoroutine(MeteorShowerCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator MeteorShowerCoroutine(){
    var startTime = Time.time;
    var delay = new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    do
    {
        SpawnMeteor();
        yield return delay;
    }
    while(Time.time - startTime < _meteorShowerDuration);

    //here you can queue next meteor shower
    StartMeteorShower(30f);
}
```